# Nginx reserve-proxy https and http connect error

Tags: docker, nginx, https, devops

First of all, I have an nginx reserve-proxy for my development server. My development server has backend and frontend with docker containers. I use nginx, letsencrypt for https. When I go to my website ,
frontend go out with https and frontend(https) cannot connect to backend api(http). I'm nood in programming but please help me to find out more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have both frontend and backend on https , if you will remove redirect from nginx file and access your site via http , you will see everything is working fine.

You need to re-install lets encrypt and when it prompts which domains it needs to cover  select both frontend and backend.

Hope it Helps .